# GooglePlus API - (401) Invalid Credentials error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus

We have code that was working perfectly to access the Googleplus Api, but now it inexplicably no longer works, instead returning a "(401) Invalid Credentials" error when this line is called:

```
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
```

Here is the full code snippet (php):

```
try
{
    $client = new apiClient();

    $client->setApplicationName("Google OAuth");
    $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_API_REDIRECT_URI);
    $client->setDeveloperKey('XXX');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));

    $plus = new apiPlusService($client);

    $oauth2 = new apiOauth2Service($client);

    $client->authenticate();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();

    if (isset($token))
        $client->setAccessToken($token);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
         $me = $plus->people->get('me');
    }
}
catch (Exception $x)
{
    echo "Stack: " . $x->getTraceAsString() . "<br />";
    echo "Message: " . $x->getMessage() . "<br />";
    echo "File: " . $x->getFile() . "<br />";
    echo "Line: " . $x->getLine(). "<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when user **denied access** to my aplication, and the token remained in the DB (or session). The **API was trying to authenticate using old token.** You need to check

```
if(strpos($x->getMessage(), 'Invalid Credentials')) {
   unset($_SESSION['access_token'];
}
```

and also remove any relevant data from your db.

Answer (score 0):

What fails? the first call to authorize, or the 2nd one to get the token ?

Check the URLs that are sent, it will be easier to inspect the issue.
and: Google might have changed their oAuth APIs?

Comment: That's the strange thing, both those calls work fine (I can get auth & get the token), it's when I make a call to retrieve a profile that the error occurs.

Comment: So you have a valid token? can you paste it here? You get the error when you try to use it? What is the error that you get?

Comment: Yep I get a valid token (too long to paste in this comment).  The error I get when I use it is simply: "Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me: (401) Invalid Credentials".  Not sure how this is possible since I can get the token no problem.

Comment: and do you use this token and put it in the header of your GET call to the Google API?

Comment: so i guess it's not an oAuth issue, but Google API one. Is it possible that Google have changed the API? did u try to search in their docs?

Comment: I have the same issue but it happens only for some users on my site. All other users (that is Google users) work fine. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Everything checks out as far as I can tell, it's possible that something went wrong with the credentials associated with your account.

To verify this, try using another account to access the API or try revoking your application from Google accounts. To revoke your application from your account:

1. Navigate to this page: https://www.google.com/settings/account
2. Click the **Security** link and then click the **Manage access** button on the bottom of the page.
3. Find the application that corresponds to your site and click

After your site/application is revoked, go back to your site and then re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused when you login from other device using same credentials and then logout .